# How to disable recursion of folders in the Google Drive API (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

In my app I use the Google Drive API. I get file list and load it to the TableView. But in the TableView I see files and folders from root directory and files and folders from subfolders. But I need to navigate to the files in the subfolder only when I tap on the appropriate row.  How can I disable recursion? And how should I implement the transition inside a subfolder in the `didSelectRow` function?
Thanks for help.

```
...
var unreformedFileList: [AnyObject] = []
var fileListTicket: GTLRServiceTicket?
...
private lazy var driveService: GTLRDriveService = {
        let service = GTLRDriveService()
        if let user = GlobalEntitie.Variable.googleUser {
        service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
        }
        service.shouldFetchNextPages = true
        service.isRetryEnabled = true
        return service
    }()
...
var files: [FileModelProtocol] {
        guard let files = unreformedFileList as? [GTLRDrive_File] else { return [] }
        return files.map { GoogleDriveFileModel($0) }
    }
...
func fetchFileList(path: String?, _ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
        query.fields = "kind,nextPageToken,files(mimeType,id,kind,name,webViewLink,thumbnailLink,trashed)"

        fileListTicket = driveService.executeQuery(query,
                                                   completionHandler: { [weak self] (_, resultObject, error) in
                                                    
                                                    if let error = error {
                                                        debugPrint("driveService.executeQuery error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                                        return
                                                    }
                                                    guard let self = self,
                                                          let fileList = resultObject as? GTLRDrive_FileList,
                                                          let unreformedFileList = fileList.files else { return }
                                                    self.unreformedFileList = []
                                                for file in unreformedFileList {
                                                    
                                                    if file.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" {
                                                        self.unreformedFileList.insert(file, at: 0)
                                                    } else {
                                                        if file.mimeType == "audio/mpeg" ||
                                                            file.mimeType == "audio/x-wav" ||
                                                            file.mimeType == "audio/aac" {
                                                            self.unreformedFileList.append(file)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                    self.fileListTicket = nil

                                                    completion()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

In Google Drive API v3 in order to list files inside a specific folder/subfloder you will have to pass the folder File ID to the q query parameter in the API call.

With the q parameter you can filter the output of the `list` method using these [options](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#search_for_specific_files_or_folders_on_the_current_users_my_drive).

Then you can list the folder content querying the `list` endpoint like this:

```
q="driveFolderID"+in+parents
```

### Reference

[Google Drive Files list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I disable recursion now?

Comment: You will have to filter the output to just files and folders in your `root` . From there you can use the fetched folder IDs to build next requests on `didSelectRow` handler.

Comment: @VyacheslavBakinkskiy If the answer solves your problem you should accept it in order to help other users to find the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Swift 5:**

In the function `fetchFileList:`, I had to use variable `folderID` in which I store the current folder ID:

```
...
query.q = "'\(folderID)' in parents"
...
```

But when I get the first time the list of files, I must use:

```
folderID = "root"
```

to display the contents of the root folder.
Then when I want to go to a subfolder I have to use its folder ID.

At what point to change the variable `folderID` you can think of yourself. This is not relevant to this question. I will just say that I change it at the time of creating a new TableViewController in which I display a list of files when going to a subfolder in `didSelectRow` function.